Java Spring Boot Cassandra: Error while opening new channel, having two nodes
[s0|/ip_address_node2:9042]  Error while opening new channel \
  (ConnectionInitException: [s0|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, \
  step 1 (STARTUP { \
    CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, \
    DRIVER_NAME=Apache Cassandra Java Driver, \
    DRIVER_VERSION=4.18.1, \
    CLIENT_ID=67d065fa-b9b2-44ff-a162-cb7b15de06ab
  }): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException))

Above WARN is prompting with ip of 2nd Node
Made sure: both nodes are on same datacenter, rack, clusterName
What's causing this issue? and its fixes
any good code repo for java 21 Spring-boot 3.3.0 using cassandra as DB

Have you specified both nodes as connection points in the application config?

Also, I built a Vaadin-SpringBoot-Astra(Cassandra) app for my Java 21 book, if that will help. repo: https://github.com/aploetz/MovieApp/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file

not using astra, using hosted cassandra on vm's
i have added connection points for all nodes in cassandra,
FYI: having one datacenter, same rack,  have added seeds connection, on both nodes
using 'spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra' dependency
